# Root node in ASP.NET TreeView is not active

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I have the following problem with TreeView. Here's some code:

```
PopulateTreeNode(dsList, null, "0");
```

The function for populating the tree:

```
private void PopulateTreeNode(DataSet dsList, TreeNode parent, string parentID)
{
    TreeNodeCollection baseNodes;

    if (parent == null)
    {
        baseNodes = TreeView1.Nodes;
    }
    else
    {
        baseNodes = parent.ChildNodes;
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in dsList.Tables[0].Select("ParentNodeID = " + parentID))
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        string rowID = row["ID"].ToString();


        node.Text = row["Description"].ToString();
        node.Value = rowID;
        node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;

        baseNodes.Add(node);

        PopulateTreeNode(dsList, node, rowID);

    }
}
```

Then I do the following to collapse all but the root node:

```
  TreeView1.CollapseAll();
  TreeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();
```

Everything works perfect except for the root node, it can't be selected, and it can't be collapsed and then expanded back. It always stays like this:

[image]

What can be wrong about it? Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE** Okay, in case anyone will somehow come across such a problem - it solved itself after our project was switched to ASP.NET 4.0 from 2.0.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the root node is unselectable? Or is it selectable, but does nothing when you click it? The only way i know to make a node unselectable is to set SelectAction="None" on it.

Comment: The node is selectable, it just doesn't react when I try to click on it. SelectAction is Expand, I checked that.